# Basic Coding for ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I'm starting to get into ColdFusion and my teacher is a little lacking in explanation. What does LTE mean. As in..

```
<cfloop condition = "y LTE 5>
```

Thanks

Comment: "Less than or equal"?  Time to go read the manuals.  (I'm guessing that you are you missing a closing quote mark)

Comment: It means Less than or Equal To. In your case, it means loop till the condition "y is less than or equal to 5" is true. Also you need as @IraBaxter said you are missing ending double quote. Try this site, it is very good for newbies http://www.learncfinaweek.com/

Comment: Yes, I'm new. Tried Googling but didn't find much.

Comment: @drago354, I guess you need to sharpen your googling skill as well.
If you tried searching properly you will get proper result. Try this link, https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=coldfusion%20LTE to search what you wanted to know.
Also sharpen your googling skill with http://www.google.com/insidesearch/landing/powersearching.html

Comment: A google search string of "ColdFusion lte" was pretty effective for me.

Comment: [CFML Reference](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Adobe+ColdFusion+CFML+Reference) - [Expressions Developing Guide](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Expressions-Developing+guide)

Comment: Stackoverflow usually has a great answer for many issues. Also find a copy of allaire The ColdFusion Web Application Construction Kit 3rd edition for Version 4.0 by Ben Forta. Mine is worn out. The last section shows simple examples on the most common tags. An amazing book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LTE Less than OR Equal
This is equivalent to <= in any other scripting language. Yo will be better served by reading about ColdFusion operators. CFSCRIPT, a coldfusion scripting tag allow you to write code in scripts if you feel comfortable with that and if you have learned any other programming language.

```
LTE = <=
GTE = >=
GT  = >
LT  = <
EQ  = ==
```

and many more.